# CONVERTING HTML5 input type date to string

Tags: php, mysql, html, stored-procedures

My PHP code

```
<?php include 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
$date = $_POST['datefield'];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));

$result = mysql_query("Call seat(".$newDate.")");

if($result == FALSE){
    echo "Sorry Query Failed!";
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
}

}
?>

html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="date" name="datefield"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitbtn">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This calls the stored procedure with definition:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `seat`(IN `dateP` VARCHAR(20))
NO SQL
begin
declare i int default 1;
while i < 250 do
insert into seat (Seat_ID,dateP) values (i,dateP);
set i = i + 1;
end while;
end
```

Table seat has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `seat` (
`ID` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Seat_ID` int(4) NOT NULL,
`Row_ID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`Col_ID` int(4) NOT NULL,
`Amount` int(3) NOT NULL,
`DateP` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 )
```

here the DateP column is inserted as 0000-00-00 in all the 250 rows.
please help me where i went wrong.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

php date-function wants timestamp and html5 date input returns date format. why not use the date format directly? (not sure but wild guess)

```
$date = $_POST['datefield'];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));   /* <-- REMOVE THIS LINE? */
$result = mysql_query("Call seat(".$date.")");
```

Question: Is Mysql case sensitive. You have in table DateP and dateP in procedure

```
insert into seat (Seat_ID,dateP) values (i,dateP); /* <-- Change first dateP -> DateP */
```

Ather question (im not familiar with procedures): what happens if you use the variable dateP in the insert field names is it variable or string?

Comment: The prob was here $result = mysql_query("Call seat(".$newDate.")");   I Replaced it with $result = mysql_query("Call seat("$date")");

Comment: That look's somehow wrong (double quotes inside double quotes). Is it working now? maybe you could use mysql_query("Call seat(\"{$date}\")")

Comment: I hope you do better with your coding than asking help and then thanking if you get help. Good luck with your homework.